# Installing VB6 runtime on Server 2008 x64 for use with ASP.NET Solution

Tags: asp.net, vb6, runtime, interop, windows-server-2008-r2

I have an ASP.NET solution which uses a COM DLL written in VB6.

I've referenced the Interop in my solution and I call its functionality on my local machine running Windows 8.1 x64 and it works perfectly but when I deploy to the Windows 2008 R2 x64 web server I get the following error:

App_Code -> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {A65D084F-7B19-4697-8BA4-C60B4E670CA3} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

By running Dependency Walker on the library I can see that the file MSVBVM60.dll cannot be found so I have installed the VB6 and VB6SP6 runtime files to no avail.

Please help.

Comment: Have you given permissions for the IIS user account to the DLL?

Comment: The VB6 core runtimes should be preinstalled out of the box.  More likely your ASP.NET code is not running in a 32-bit context so it can make use of the 32-bit DLL.  Sounds like at least an IIS configuration issue.